# How to speed up Sails start time (Using Vagrant on a Windows Host)

Tags: sails.js

I'm seeing Sails.js v0.10.5 take a long time to start which is painful for development.

My sails project is nearly empty so it's surprising that it takes so long.

How can I speed up Sails' start time?

Edit: This wasn't a problem with sails, rather I was using vagrant with virtualbox's default folder sharing which is very slow. I've switched over to rsync sharing and things are much much faster now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Vagrant to manage your dev environment, don't use Virtualbox's default folder sharing. I used the rsync folder sharing and that made Sails about 10x faster to start.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing anything about your setup, it's impossible to say.  Running `sails lift` on a new project takes exactly one second for me.

Try running `sails lift --verbose` or `sails lift --silly` to see where the bottlenecks are in your startup.  Typically it's either a database adapter (especially if it's connecting remotely) or something in your **config/bootstrap.js** file.

Answer (score 1):

set `migrate: 'safe'` in `config/models.js` file , will help to speed up.
more detail look here : http://sailsjs.org/#!/documentation/concepts/ORM/model-settings.html

Answer (score 0):

my projects took about 14s to start up.
the reason for my case is : I got a large project with too many model, hook orm occupy most about 50% of the time.
so my solutions is I depart my node to server node , which is split a monolith to soa, ref [uber archi](https://eng.uber.com/soa/)